# android device monitor is not available in my android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, database, device, monitor, pull

My android studio 3.0.1 version doesn't have the Android Device Monitor neither icon nor in tool bar. Anyone knows what to do to solve this problem? I want to pull data from my emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Device File Explorer](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer) to get the data from an emulator or an actual device.

> 1. Click View > Tool Windows > Device File Explorer or click the Device File Explorer button in the tool window bar to open the Device
>      File Explorer.
> 2. Select a device from the drop down list.
> 3. Interact with the device content in the file explorer window. Right-click on a file or directory to create a new file or directory,
>      save the selected file or directory to your machine, upload, delete,
>      or synchronize. Double-click a file to open it in Android Studio.

[image]

Comment: i want to pull my database from it..?